# CakePHP 1.2 pagination link is disabled

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

In my CakePHP application, my custom pagination is not working at all. There are three problems I'm facing:

1. It's always showing only a single page
2. Links are disabled
3. Ending record is incorrect. I have total 7 records. I used `LIMIT 3`, so only 3 records should be visible per page, the last record being record no. 3 in the first page. But instead, record no. 7 is being displayed as the ending record in the first page.

I have set `debug mode` to `2` to try to find out any problems that may exist in my code. But was unable to find any.

Here's my controller code:

```
var $name = 'HomeLoanDistributions';

function index() {
        $user = $this->Session->read('User');
        $user_role = $user['User']['user_role_id'];
        $actions = $this->Session->read('actions');
        $display_actions = array();

        foreach ($actions as $action) {
            array_push($display_actions, $action['pm_controller_actions']['name']);
        }
        $this->set('display_actions', $display_actions);
        $this->set('user_role', $user_role);


        $branch_id = $this->branchCheck();
        $this->set('branch_id', $branch_id);
        $conditions = array('branch_id' => $branch_id);

        $this->set('HomeLoanDistributions', $this->paginate($conditions));
        $this->HomeLoanDistribution->Branch->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('BranchInformation', $this->HomeLoanDistribution->Branch->read(array('Branch.id', 'Branch.name', 'Region.name', 'District.name', 'SubDistrict.name', 'Cluster.name'), $branch_id));
    }

function branchCheck() {
        // check for matching branch

        if (isset($this->params['named']['branch_id'])) {


            if (empty($this->params['named']['branch_id'])) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Branch could not be found. Please, try again.', true));
                $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'Branches', 'action' => 'index', $this->name));
            } else {
                $this->HomeLoanDistribution->Branch->recursive = -1;

                if ($this->HomeLoanDistribution->Branch->find('count', array('conditions' => array('Village.id' => $this->params['named']['branch_id']))) != 1) {

                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Branch could not be found. Please, try again.', true));
                    $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'Branches', 'action' => 'index', $this->name));
                }
            }
            return $this->params['named']['branch_id'];
        }
    }
```

Here's my model code:

```
 var $name = 'HomeLoanDistribution';
    var $actsAs = array('Logable' => array(
            'userModel' => 'User',
            'userKey' => 'user_id',
            'change' => 'list', // options are 'list' or 'full'
            'description_ids' => TRUE // options are TRUE or FALSE
    ));
    var $validate = array(
        'entry_date' => array(
            'rule' => 'date',
            'message' => 'Enter a valid date',
            'allowEmpty' => true
        ),
        'branch_id' => array('numeric'),
        'customer_id' => array('numeric'),
        'home_group_id' => array('numeric'),
        'voucher_no' => array('numeric'),
        'no_of_installment' => array('numeric'),
        'loan_amount' => array('numeric'),
        'service_charge' => array('numeric'),
        'security' => array('numeric'),
        'loan_taken_term' => array('numeric'),
        'installment_amount' => array('numeric'),
        'installment_service_charge' => array('numeric'),
        'effective_date' => array('numeric'),
    );

    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Branch' => array(
            'className' => 'Branch',
            'foreignKey' => 'branch_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => 'id,name',
            'order' => ''
        ),
    );
function paginate($conditions, $fields, $order, $page = 1, $recursive = null, $extra = array()) {

    $recursive = 0;

    $fields =  array('entry_date');
    $group = array('branch_id');
    $order = array('entry_date DESC');
    $limit = 3;
    return $this->find('all', compact('fields', 'order', 'limit', 'page', 'recursive', 'group'));
    $this->paginateCount($conditions);
}

function paginateCount($conditions = null, $recursive = 0, $extra = array()) {

    $recursive = 0;
    $fields =  array('entry_date');
    $group = array('branch_id');
    $order = array('entry_date DESC');
    $results = $this->find('all', compact('fields', 'order', 'limit', 'page', 'recursive', 'group'));
    return count($results);
}
```

And my view codes:

```
    <?php echo $this->renderElement('BranchInformation'); ?>
    <?php
    $paginator->options(
            array(
                'url' => array('controller' => 'HomeLoanDistributions', 'action' => $this->action, 'branch_id' => $BranchInformation['Branch']['id'])));
    ?>
    <h2><?php __('Home Loan Distribution'); ?></h2>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo 'SL NO.'; ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $paginator->sort('Loan Distribution Month', 'entry_date'); ?></th>

            <th class="actions"><?php __('Actions'); ?></th>
            <!--th class="actions"><--?php __('Actions');?></th-->
        </tr>
        <?php

        $start = (int) $paginator->counter('%start%');
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($HomeLoanDistributions as $HomeLoanDistribution):
            $class = null;
            if ($i++ % 2 == 0) {
                $class = ' class="altrow"';
            }

            ?>
            <tr<?php echo $class; ?>>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $start++; ?>
                </td>
                <td class="taRight">
                    <?php
                    $returnDate = date_format(date_create($HomeLoanDistribution['HomeLoanDistribution']['entry_date']), "M-Y");
                    print_r($returnDate);
                    ?>
                </td>

                <td class="actions">
                    <?php echo $html->link(__('View', true), array('action' => 'view', $HomeLoanDistribution['HomeLoanDistribution']['entry_date'], 'branch_id' => $BranchInformation['Branch']['id'])); ?>
                    <?php echo $html->link(__('Edit', true), array('action' => 'edit', $HomeLoanDistribution['HomeLoanDistribution']['entry_date'], 'branch_id' => $BranchInformation['Branch']['id'])); ?>
                    <?php echo $html->link(__('Delete', true), array('action' => 'delete', $HomeLoanDistribution['HomeLoanDistribution']['entry_date'], 'branch_id' => $BranchInformation['Branch']['id']), null, sprintf(__('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', true), $HomeLoanDistribution['HomeLoanDistribution']['entry_date'])); ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="paging">
    <?php echo $paginator->prev('<< ' . __('previous', true), array(), null, array('class' => 'disabled')); ?>  
    <?php echo $paginator->numbers(); ?>
    <?php echo $paginator->next(__('next', true) . ' >>', array(), null, array('class' => 'disabled')); ?>
    <span style="float:right;"><?php
        echo $paginator->counter(array(
            'format' => __('Page %page% of %pages%, showing %current% records out of %count% total, starting on record %start%, ending on %end%', true)
        ));
        ?></span>
</div>
```

My CakePHP version is 1.2.5 and my PHP version is 5.2.11, since this is a very old project back from 2008-09.

Comment: $this->set('HomeLoanDistributions', $this->paginate($conditions)); what did this ? isnt $this->HomeLoanDistribution->paginate($conditions,$fields); ?

Comment: @MouradK I'm new to CakePHP, so I don't know much about the conventions. Furthermore, this code was written by another person.

Answer (score 0):

When he called:

```
$this->set('HomeLoanDistributions', $this->paginate($conditions));
```

I think he used : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html

and $limit should be passed in configuration  of PaginationComponent .. isnt it ?

does there are $paginate var in AppController or in this one ?

---

Edit : try use paginate from your MOdel :

Change

```
$this->set('HomeLoanDistributions', $this->paginate($conditions));
```

by

```
$this->set('HomeLoanDistributions', $this->HomeLoanDistribution->paginate($conditions) );
```

Comment: I have `var $paginate_limit = 15;` in AppController.

Comment: which cakephp version are you using ? try to change with $paginate_limit = 3 ;

Comment: Didn't I mention in my question that I'm using Cake 1.2.5 ?

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/1.2/en/The-Manual/Common-Tasks-With-CakePHP/Pagination.html this is the good documentation , it depends really on your Controller config and AppController,  can you create a https://gist.github.com/ and share us ?

Comment: I don't have account in GitHub. How about I post the codes here in my question?

Comment: I changed `paginate_limit = 3`in AppController. Still not getting results. There is no such thing as PaginationComponent in the Components folder of controllers.

Comment: it s a default Component, and for use it you just had to  var $paginate = array(
        'limit' => 25,
        'order' => array(
            'Post.title' => 'asc'
        )
    );   in the controller, it depends on your implementation... if you can copy paste

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. Previously, I used to get 3 records out of 7 for setting `$limit = 3` inside my paginate() function in model. Now I get all 7 records.

Comment: but your HomeLoanDistribution::paginate($condtions,...) is not call in your Controller... change   $this->set('HomeLoanDistributions', $this->paginate($conditions)); by $this->set('HomeLoanDistributions', $this->HomeLoanDistribution->paginate($conditions) ); and it will call it

Comment: `Fatal Error: Call to a member function paginate() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\sdb\app\controllers\home_loan_distributions_controller.php on line 31`

Comment: just do this before : $this->loadModel('HomeLoanDistribution')